# Can a neural network be used to predict a sequence of integers based on dataset of previously produced random numbers?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction, randomness

What i really want to do, is to predict an integer sequence of (5 numbers with values from 1 to 50) for example based on a big dataset of other 5 numbers sequences with same values range created by the same random number generator. I suppose there is a way to train based on the dataset and the program will find a pattern or based on the most common numbers predict the next number sequence. The more numbers will predict in the sequence correctly the better of course. Any help, directions and preferably python code would be greatly appreciated.

I recently read the following  [can-a-neural-network-be-used-to-predict-the-next-pseudo-random-number](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/can-a-neural-network-be-used-to-predict-the-next-pseudo-random-number) and i am new to the AI field. The proposed code while it creates a sequence of 25 numbers it ends showing 20 numbers i do not understand why. It seems they try to do something similar if i understand correctly

I tried The code here [can-a-neural-network-be-used-to-predict-the-next-pseudo-random-number](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/can-a-neural-network-be-used-to-predict-the-next-pseudo-random-number)

It shows always the same numbers no matter how many epochs and or iterations i do is that normal?
Is the last code close to what i want to accomplish?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The post you linked to clearly states that pseudo random number cannot be predicted. Their randomness is made to be nearly perfect, and if you ever found a way to even predict a pseudo random number with 20% chance of correct, the security of the entire world would be vulnerable to attacks, as things ranges from cryptocurrency and secure data transfer is all protected by pseudo random number.

Answer (score 1):

If is a truly a random number, and you could guess each of the next successive five in sequence, then you could win the lottery consistently.

This is one of the first tasks many people try to do when first learning machine learning.  If the lottery is truly a random physical process with fair, i.e., balanced ping pong balls, then you cannot predict which 5 or 6 numbers will come up next.  The Lottery Commissions around the world go through great pains to ensure that the lotteries are fair and not fraudulent.

It looks like you are using a random seed number, that is why you are getting the next number always the same.

Good luck learning your numbers !